# How to declare type of this function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm using [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) library and trying to write simple function:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as GV

setCharges :: GV.Vector v Double => 
              Network -> v Double -> Network
setCharges n cs = n{nodes = GV.zipWith setCharge (nodes n) cs}
```

With `XFlexibleContexts` ghc accepts type declaration but complain near `cs` varibale

```
Could not deduce (v ~ Vector)
```

I have

```
nodes n :: Data.Vector.Vector Node
setCharge :: Node -> Double -> Node
```

Don't really get, what the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just what GHC says: the `setCharges` signature only requires that `v` is some instance of the *class* `Data.Vector.Generic.Vector`. The `nodes` field of `Network`, OTOH, is always one particular type, namely `Data.Vector.Vector`, which sure enough is an instance of the `Vector` class, but there can be others as well. So you can't just replace this field with some other type, no matter if it's an instance of `GV.Vector` or not. But there's a generic function to [`convert`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic.html#g:37) between such instances, use that and you'll be fine:

```
setCharges n cs = n{nodes = GV.zipWith setCharge (nodes n) (GV.convert cs)}
```

Alternatively, you could design the `Network` record so the `nodes` field is in fact polymorphic, i.e. can hold arbitrary instances of the class rather than one particular type. This is called an *existential*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification       #-}

data Network = Network { ...
                       , nodes :: forall v . GV.Vector v => v Double
                       , ...
                       }
```

But it's generally considered a bit of an antipattern, at least if there isn't a particular reason to go this route.

Comment: Woha, I missed `convert`. But in no way would've I figured out to use it, so thanks for explanation.