# Any reasons to restrict vector functions to one instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141442/how-to-declare-type-of-this-function) about `Data.Vector.Generic.Vector` instances I began to wonder, why

```
zipWith :: (Vector v a, Vector v b, Vector v c)
        => (a -> b -> c) -> v a -> v b -> v c
zipWith f xs ys = unstream (Stream.zipWith f (stream xs) (stream ys))
```

and not

```
zipWith :: (GV.Vector v1 a, GV.Vector v2 b, GV.Vector v3 c) 
        => (a -> b -> c) -> v1 a -> v2 b -> v3 c
zipWith f xs ys = unstream (Stream.zipWith f (stream xs) (stream ys))
```

?

Second one compiles just fine. Are there any particular reasons to restrict all such function to one instance? Because for me

```
v1 = Data.Vector.fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
v2 = Data.Vector.Unboxed.fromList [6,7,8,9] :: Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Int
v3 = foo (*) v1 v2 :: Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Int
v4 = foo (*) v1 v2 :: Data.Vector.Vector Int
```

looks WAY more 'generic'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage, IMO, of a single `v` in the signature is that this can then always be infered from any one of the arguments. With the more polymorphic approach, you'd end up having to write awkward explicit type signatures for intermediate expressions (probably necessiating `-XScopedTypeVariables` when typically the choice would be just "use the same `Vector` flavour as for the other argument" (which is probably the best choice performance-wise, and just the obvious one). Often it simply won't matter much, then it's nice not to have to worry about type signatures at all. OTOH, if you *need* to combine different `Vector` instances, the precise type being fixed elsewhere, it's a trivial matter of throwing in `GV.convert` before one of the arguments to get to the more polymorphic version. Much easier that making it less polymorphic, somewhat surprisingly.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, when using generic interface for construction ambiguity would arise.